# How to debug cmake

Tags: debugging, cmake, qt6

I am trying to figure out why configure step for Qt6.4 on MacOS fails.

As investigating logs and googling leads nowhere I started to debug underlying cmake.

Now I am in function that looks like:

```
function(qt_evaluate_to_boolean expressionVar)
    if(${${expressionVar}})
        set(${expressionVar} ON PARENT_SCOPE)
    else()
        set(${expressionVar} OFF PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endfunction()
```

Where expressionVar is TEST_openssl_headers.

The result of this operation is FALSE. I need to know why.

In the logs there is no TEST_openssl_headers, so apparently the test compilation is not even called.

Why? How can I know what happens at the "if" line? Where it calls? How does it evaluate if it is true?

Comment: "In the logs there is no TEST_openssl_headers, so apparently the test compilation is not even called." - What kind of logs do you mean? Do you use [variable_watch](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) for watch for the variable? How have you deduce that dereferencing of `TEST_openssl_headers` is never performed?

Comment: Thanks, until now never heard about variable_watch. Seems like it is exactly what I wanted and needed. Thanks.